# Construction of GF($q$) as a concatenation of subgroups

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Consider a subset $\mathcal{J}^*$ of $\left\{ {1,2,...,m} \right\}$ such that each element in $\mathcal{J}^*$ divides $m$ and $k'$ divides $k$ for all $k,k' \in \mathcal{J}^*$, $k' \le k$.

Let us denote by $\mathcal{S}_k$ ($k=1,2,...,m$) a subgroup of cardinality $2^k$ of the additive group of $\rm GF$($q$). We choose $\mathcal{S}_k$ as the unique subfield of cardinality $2^k$ (which is in particular a subgroup) if $k \in \mathcal{J}^*$. For the remaining values of $k$, we choose subgroups.

As an example, if GF($64$) then $\mathcal{S}_1$, $\mathcal{S}_3$ or $\mathcal{S}_1$ and $\mathcal{S}_2$ are valid choices for subfields.

Is there a choice of subgroups among $\mathcal{S}_k$ (i.e., apart from the choice of subfields indexed in $\mathcal{J}^*$) such that $\mathcal{S}_1 \subset \mathcal{S}_2 \subset .... \subset \mathcal{S}_m = {\rm GF}(q)$?

Comment: Could you show us how far you have got with $\text{GF}(64)$?

Comment: But don't you ask for a chain of $m$ subgroups?

Comment: But ${\rm GF}(4)$ is not a subfield of ${\rm GF}(8)$, so the answer to your question is no.

Comment: I am trying to suggest that you need to look at the lattice of subfields of $GF(q)$ and then review your conjecture (@DerekHolt has put it more crudely).

Comment: And it isn't so, as I crudely said before, the answer to you question is no there is no such construction.

Comment: @DerekHolt Please note that I modified my question. Now the subfields chosen for $\mathcal{S}_k$ must be subfields with respect to each other.

Comment: @rtc. Please give us your chain of $6$ subgroups for $\text{GF}(2^6)$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Assume that $\mathcal{S}_1$, $\mathcal{S}_3$ are picked as subfields. In particular, they can be viewed as subspaces of GF($q$). As a start, I am trying to figure out whether I can construct a basis for $\mathcal{S}_2$ (say) by adding one basis element to the basis of $\mathcal{S}_1$, such that the elements of $\mathcal{S}_2$ are necessarily contained in $\mathcal{S}_3$.

Comment: I cannot see that you have changed your question at all. You are still requiring that ${\mathcal S}_l$ is the unique subfield of order $2^l$ for all $l$ dividing $m$. So you have no choice for ${\mathcal S}_2$ and ${\mathcal S}_3$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Please note that $\mathcal{S}_k$ with $k \notin \mathcal{J}^*$ should be chosen as subgroups and not as subfields. In addition, I now require that each chosen subfield of GF($q$) must be a subfield of any larger subfield.

Comment: Now the answer is yes, because you can choose ${\mathcal S}_k$ for $k \not\in {\mathcal J}^*$ to be any subgroup of the size $2^k$ that satisfies the required containments.

Comment: But why such subgroups must exist?

Comment: I think it is simplest to think in terms of vector spaces over $GF(2)$. A subfield is also a subspace, and you can fill in the sequence simply by extending the bases of the flag of subspaces in such a way that you respect the known unique intermediate points (= the subfields included in the sequence).

Comment: Now counting the number of solutions to your (much revised) problem would be fun. And @JyrkiLahtonen has told you how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the comments, the answer is yes, there is such choice of subgroups. The idea is to consider the subfields as subspaces and then to extend the bases (as pointed out by J. Lahtonen).