# Manipulating additive subgroups of the finite field GF($2^m$)

Tags: finite-groups, field-theory, finite-fields

Consider the field construction as in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166598/construction-of-gfq-as-a-series-of-subgroups), where GF($2^m$) is obtained as a concatenation of additive subgroups of cardinality $2^j$ for $j=0,1,...,m$. In this question, no assumption is made that subgroups of cardinality $2^{j'}$ for $j'$ that divides $s$ need to be subfields.

Assume that two subgroups $\mathcal{S}_a$ and $\mathcal{S}_{b}$ are chosen (following the notations in the link above, where $\mathcal{S}_a$ is of cardinality $2^a$ and $\mathcal{S}_b$ is of cardinality $2^b$), where w.l.o.g. $\mathcal{S}_a \subseteq \mathcal{S}_b$ and $a+b \le m$. Can we always find an element $g \ne 0$ of the field such that $\{g \cdot {S_a}\}\bigcap {{S_b}}  = \left\{ 0 \right\}$?

Note that $g \cdot {S_a}$ is an additive subgroup of GF($q$). Considering the subgroups as subspaces over GF($2$), my first thought was to look for $g$, such that when multiplied by the basis elements of $\mathcal{S}_a$, lead to a disjoint set of basis elements. However, I am not sure how to do this in a systematic way.

---

**Addendum:**
For fixed values of $a,b$ such that $a+b \le m$ such $g$ can indeed be found. However, is there a "universal" value of $g$ such that
$$\{ g \cdot {S_a}\} \bigcap {{S_b}}  = \left\{ 0 \right\}$$
$$\{ {S_a}\} \bigcap {\left\{ {g \cdot {S_b}} \right\}}  = \left\{ 0 \right\}$$
for **every** pair $\mathcal{S}_a,\mathcal{S}_b$ such that $a+b \le m$?

Comment: What does it mean by cardinalities sum to $2^m$? Is it $|S_a|+| S_b|=2^m$?

Comment: To have the sum $2^m$, we know $|S_a|\leq 2^{m-1}$, $|S_b|\leq 2^{m-1}$. Then both must be $|S_a|=|S_b|=2^{m-1}$. Also, by $S_a\subset S_b$, we must have $S_a= S_b$. Am I missing something?

Comment: The case $g=0$ is a trivial case. Do you want to remove it?

Comment: Another trivial case is when $b=m$. Then $a=0$.

Comment: Also, it seems that it is enough to consider $a+b=m$.

Comment: @i707107 I also think that $a+b=m$ is the extreme case. However, I don't have a formal proof.

Comment: That's because $a=b-m$ is the maximal possible dimension for $S_a$.

Comment: @i707107 Yes, if for such $\mathcal{S}_a$ we can find a $g$, this $g$ will hold for all $\mathcal{S}_{a'} \subseteq \mathcal{S}_a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to consider $1\leq a$ and  $a+b=m$, otherwise it becomes trivial case. Let $\{v_1, \ldots , v_a\}$ be a basis for $S_a$, and $\{w_1, \ldots, w_b\}$ be a basis for $S_b$. Let $F^*$ be the set of nonzero elements in $GF(2^m)$.

We find an element $g\in F^*$ satisfying:
$$
g \cdot v_1 \notin S_b.\ \ \ (1)
$$
Since multiplication by nonzero element is injective, there are at least $2^m - 1-2^b$  elements $g$ satisfy the above.

We also want $g$ to satisfy:
$$
g\cdot v_2 \notin \mathrm{Span}(S_b \cup \{g\cdot v_1\}). \ \ \ (2)
$$

The negation of this condition is in fact the existence of $a_{b+1}\in \{0,1\}$ such that 
$$
g\cdot v_2 = a_1 w_1 + \cdots + a_b w_b + a_{b+1} g\cdot v_1
$$

which is equivalent to 
$$
g \cdot (v_2 - a_{b+1} v_1) \in S_b.
$$
We avoid all $g$ possibly satisfying the above. There are two choices for $a_{b+1}$ and $v_2 - a_{b+1} v_1 \neq 0$. Thus, multiplication by $v_2 - a_{b+1} v_1$ is injective. Thus, there are at least $2^m-1-2^b-2^{b+1}$ elements $g$ satisfy both (1) and (2).

We use this idea  to find $g\in F^*$ satisfying (1) and:

For all $1\leq j\leq a-1$, 
$$
g\cdot v_{j+1} \notin \mathrm{Span}(S_b \cup \{g\cdot v_1 , \ldots , g\cdot v_j\}). \ \ \ (j+1)
$$
Then the negation of the above is satisfied by at most $2^{j+b}$ elements $g\in F^*$. Therefore there are at least $2^m-1-\sum_{j=b}^{m-1} 2^j$ elements $g\in F^*$ satisfying (1) and ($j+1$) for all $1\leq j\leq a-1$.

We have $2^m-1-\sum_{j=b}^{m-1} 2^j\geq 1$. Thus, finding such $g$ is possible.

Comment: Can it be extended to cases where the exact values of $a$ and $b$ are not known? That is, we just know that $a+b \le m$ and want to find one $h$ for all cases.

Comment: This is an argument when $a$ and $b$ are fixed and satisfy $a+b=m$. If they are not known and possibly vary, then other method is probably needed.

Comment: The method I thought about is to find for each pair $(a,b)$ such that $a+b \le m$ the value of $h$ (maybe not explicitly) and finally to show that the intersection of the $h$ values is not empty. However, apart from a counting argument, this possibly requires to find the exact value of $h$. I edited the question accordingly.